# Form handler routes for image uploads

Tags: forms, model-view-controller

I have an edit page which is grows with the size of the app. We're now running in to a situation where the server side action (MVC) is handling image uploads and conversions alongside regular text saving to database.

What's the best way to make this more maintainable? Separate controller for images uploads, so that we create an writeable API? Or more actions within the same controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways, which could let you mitigate the problem with rising complexity :

- Implement [HMVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), where each controller calls sub-controllers. This would let you to split up the "update" tasks in logical and manageable chunks. Especially, if i am correct in thinking that there is more the one "update page". The HMVC structure would let you to assemble different update pages from existing fragments with quite minor additional hustle. 
  *Main disadvantage*: relatively large change in architecture.
- Split the update page(s) in smaller forms, each submitting to a different controllers action (or maybe a different controller altogether). 
  *Main disadvantage*: user can update only one part at the time
- Evolve the model layer, so that the API you use interacts with [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) instead of domain model layer. This will let you isolate the complexity of updated and provide a simpler interface to use in controller. This too would have the added benefit of composing update form(s) from manageable pieces. But i don't know the penalties that come with this approach .. never have used it myself.

The bottom line is: you will have to change one part of MVC. In your situation i would choose the HMVC way, but mostly because i am familiar with it, and multiform page might induce rage from users.

Comment: I like the sound of HMVC; in the past I delegated tasks to classes I refer to as 'components' but it never occurred to me of making them routeable. A variation I'll try is RESTful sub-controllers. It has to be verbose as we're using JavaScript a la Node.js. (Gotta make our new developers happy)